# Error on using exports in a React application - Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.js and am facing this error. A file in my project is exporting a function as follows:

```
exports.building = {
    //... //Something goes here...
};
```

And I am importing it as follows:

```
const building from "./building";
```

I have come across the following links but am unable to find a reasonable fix:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3974
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3917
- [React uncaught reference error: exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924608/react-uncaught-reference-error-exports-is-not-defined)

Comment: Can you add more code of the particular file.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `export const building = {//... //Something goes here...};` and import like `import { building } from "./building";` ?

Comment: @Max that's it! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For export use:

```
export const building = {
  //Something goes here...
};
```

For import:

```
import { building } from "./building";
```

More about imports in ES6 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796281/10048850)