# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined react-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, babeljs, sprockets, react-rails

I need to add react-rails to my rails 4 app, but it's giving me hard time to figure out.

my project uses sprockets for assets:precompilation,

this is my component:

```
import React from "react"

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<p> hello from react </p> );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

when I load the page everything works fine, except for the react component, which is just rendered as a div in the html, and in the console I see:

```
Sidebar.self.js?body=1:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at Sidebar.self.js:1:23
```

there's an initial snippet added there:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
```

That causes the problem.

I tried everything I could find:

- Webpacker (but that gave way more troubles so I removed it)
- installing https://github.com/TannerRogalsky/sprockets-es6
- [Typescript ReferenceError: exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined)
- [React uncaught reference error: exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924608/react-uncaught-reference-error-exports-is-not-defined)

and more. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (or maybe I misused one of the solutions above?)

### update

I figured that I can send babel configuration options via react-rails gem using:

```
Rails.application.config.react.jsx_transform_options = {
  plugins: ["@babel/preset-react"],
  loose: ["es6.modules"]
}
```

I'm not sure which plugins I should use, but this doesn't appear to be affecting a thing, except that it's not ignored, if I write something that is not recognised I do get an exception.